# Bitbake AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getVar'?

Tags: bitbake, openembedded

When I run bitbake I get the following :

```
ERROR: Unable to start bitbake server
ERROR: Server log for this session (/oe-core/build/bitbake-cookerdaemon.log):
--- Starting bitbake server pid 19923 at 2017-12-11 15:07:29.665036 ---
ERROR: Unable to parse /oe-core/stuff/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/data_smart.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/oe-core/stuff/openembedded-core/bitbake/lib/bb/data_smart.py", line 426, in DataSmart.expandWithRefs(s="linux${@['','-gnueabi'][bb.data.getVar('TARGET_ARCH',d,1) in ['arm', 'armeb']]}", varname='TARGET_OS'):
                 except Exception as exc:
```

I am using bitbake version 1.36 (1.34 gives me the same error) and openembedded branch pyro. I execute this in the build folder and I get the above.
My os is ubuntu 14.04.

I just installed the setup, what could be wrong?

Comment: The traceback is missing the actual exception trace.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: nope. not yet !!